# Anime where a group of 3 teenagers travel to help a land recover from an evil ruler's doings

Tags: story-identification, anime

It was an old anime where 3 teenagers journeyed to help the local area recover from what the evil ruler did to the kingdom. In one village they helped an old lady with a farm problem. Once, when they were travelling to their next destination, they were ambushed by the ruler's guards (part monsters) and managed to beat them.

Stopped by a lake once. I remember the 2 male teen heroes met up with the girl when they were travelling through a forest and found she had useful wildeness skills and knew some magic spells, and convinced her to join them after saying they could help find out about her past. She either had a bow or staff weapon and pet/guardian animal that she grew up with. The main male hero has a special sword weapon.

They managed to arrive at the main castle to see it was partially in ruin when they went to challenge the evil ruler.

That's my vague remembrance. Some could be wrong and I appreciate any help to shed light on to this. I would love to see how this series ended.

Comment: You mention that it's an old anime; do you have any idea how old?  Was it likely produced in the 80's, 90's or when?  Was it a TV series, an OAV, or possibly a single movie?

Comment: Could it be [*Sorcerous Stabber Orphen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorcerous_Stabber_Orphen)? Three main characters (two males, one female), "pet" animal (which is really a wolf-looking dragon), special sword (the Sword Of Baltanders). Great background music.

Comment: Ok well i remember viewing it in the mid 2000's so it could be made as early as the 1990's and no its not sorcerous stabber orphen. but thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 3):

I reminds me of Deltora, there are also books from scholastic that have all the stories,

Lief and Barda meet Jasmine in the forests of silence while searching for one of the gems of the belt of Deltora. They have to find all the gems and restore the belt in order to defeat the shadow lord.

There are anime chapters of Deltora in youtube, you have to pay to see them though

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... It reminds me of *[Inuyasha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuyasha#Anime)* - it ran from 2000-2004 in seven seasons. :/

I can't say for sure, but the similarities are as follows:

1. There are two male characters in the group (a half-dog demon, half-kid, with a magical sword, and a monk), and a female one with a bow (at least at some later point she has a bow, can't remember now), but there's another female character joining them later, which reminds me of the magicky one you described (though she's a demon fighter/ninja);
2. There is a two-tailed fox as a gang member/pet;
3. They go from village to village, helping people along the way, but the initial reason was to find the shards of some magical crystal.

I remember an episode where they had to face an evil lord of the village, but it turned out that he was possesed by a demon.

This is the summary of the first season on the official website:

> Kagome Higurashi, an average ninth grader, gets pulled into an ancient well by a demon, bringing her 500 years in the past to the feudal era. There, she meets Inuyasha, a half-demon who seeks the Shikon Jewel to make himself a full-fledged demon. With Inuyasha and new friends, Kagome's search for the Jewel of Four Souls begins...

Take a look at the trailer, it might help:

Comment: @LogicDictates Thanks for adding the wiki link, I forgot to paste it. *facepalm*